# What in the world is a shtender?

Tags: words, yiddish

Who made up the name shtender, and who started using the term?

Comment: It seems to me that the title of this question and its body are asking different things. The title asks for the definition, the body for the etymology. All the answers address only the definition.

Comment: Is this on topic?

Answer (score 9):

The word "shtender" (שטענדער) is Yiddish, and it's usually translated as "stander," although a more correct translation would be "lectern."  It's an object used to prop up your books at an angle, and allow for easier reading.  Some models are designed to be placed on a desk, and others, like the one pictured below, are for people who prefer to stand.

Jews don't have a monopoly on this concept, and, in fact, there are companies selling "laptop stands" to do exactly the same thing, updated for the 21st century.

Here's a picture of one of the most common types:

[image: Shtender]

Comment: Etymology is Yiddish, probably derived from German word for "stander."

Answer (score 7):

from the yiddish, meaning "stander", i.e. you stand at it to learn/daven

Answer (score 3):

The English word for it is Lectern or Podium

Answer (score 2):

There is a great description, diagram, and discussion of the educational benefits on [pages 48 and 49](http://books.google.com/books?id=xdaja3ceKc4C&lpg=PA48&ots=kAH9yxigWN&dq=shtender%20%22to%20kindle%20a%20soul%22&pg=PA48#v=onepage&q&f=false) of *[To Kindle a Soul](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1881927199)*, by Lawrence Kelemen.

Answer (score 0):

(Yid: שטענדער) A *shtender* is the podium or bookstand used by the chazan in shul.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it is more of a comment - see again the **text** of the question focused on who created the name and started using it?