# Modifying a Shtender on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat

I have a [Shtender](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1009/what-in-the-world-is-a-shtender) and it has an option to remove the top part of it and use it as a table-top Shtender. Is doing this — removing the top part to use as a table top or putting it back to be used as a regular Shtender — allowed on Shabbos?Another aspect of the question is the height can be adjusted to make it a sitting or standing Shtender  and is adjusted by using a  screw like implement is one allowed to adjust the height (My concern is Boineh or Makeh Bpatish.)

Answer (score 1):

Shulchan Shlomo 313:7 - Rabbi Shlomo Zalman Aurbach Zatzal - and [Shaalos U'Teshuvos Shevet HaLevi 6:32](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1416&st=&pgnum=33) permit adjusting the height of a Shtender on Shabbos. [Minchas Yitzchok 9:38](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1601&pgnum=50) prohibits adjusting a Shtender on Shabbos. [Thanks to RabbiKaganoff.com](http://rabbikaganoff.com/archives/354)

Comment: Does anyone address the separating the table top Shtender and reattaching? even thought according to the guy in the Judaica store it is a very recent feature but that just may be a sales Pitch

Comment: here is the one i bought if it helps:                                                     http://www.greenfieldjudaica.com/floor-shtender---fully-adjustable-STA.html

Answer (score 1):

Rivevos Ephraim 5:264 goes through this sugya,and brings opinions some which Gershon Gold already mentioned which allows adjustment on shabbas.However he brings a shittah which holds that a yeshiva shtender which is constantly adjusted is mutar,but a shtender which is used at a specific height should not be adjusted.see inside.

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1086&st=&pgnum=220&hilite=

Answer (score 0):

Rav Nissim Karelitz in Chut Shani (Shabbos 1:36) permits this based on the Chazon Ish (Orach Chaim 50:9) who permits screwing the lid of a baby bottle on, on Shabbos as the bottle is a Keli without a lid and one isn't changing anything by putting on the lid. The same applies, says the Chut Shani by a Shtender as it is usable without the top part.