# Adjusting a crutch on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work

What would be the halacha with regards to adjusting brand new crutches on Shabbos. Most modern crutches come with pins (see picture below) on either side which when pressed down can slide into the next set of holes and thereby be altered to the appropriate height.

[image]

So, within the realm of hilchos Shabbos, do we say since it was made to function like this there is no problem to do it on Shabbos as one is merely making it the right, functional height, or do we say that by adjusting is boneh (building) or is it 'makeh b'patish' (the final hammer blow) as you are making it fit for purpose and thereby turning it into a 'kli' - i.e. a bit like threading laces into new shoes (see [Mishnah Berurah 317:18](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.317.2?lang=bi&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.317.19&lang2=bi))

DISCLAIMER: I know this is a question for a LOR I am merely opening it up for discussion as a means to learn more about the subject matter and resulting Hilchos Shabbos.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I have managed to see that is helpful is [here](https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/13223), which brings a potentially similar scenario of altering the height of a shtender - but I don't have immediate access to any of the stated seforim - so if people can shed more light it would be appreciated:

> Many shtenders are tightened and loosened by the use of a screw. May one adjust the shtender by loosening and tightening the screw? Does it make a difference how often one adjusts the height?
>
> According to Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach and Rav Vozner, one may adjust the height of the shtender on Shabbos since this is considered using the shtender, not making a new appliance (Shulchan Shlomoh 313:7; Shu"t Shevet HaLevi 6:32; cf. Minchas Yitzchok 9:38, who prohibits).

So based off this psak (again I haven't seen it inside) Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach and Rav Wosner would have possibly allowed the adjustment of a crutch whilst Rav Yitzchok Yaakov Weiss (Minchas Yitzchak) wouldn't. However this is based on the assumption that it is the same screw-like mechanics?

### **EDIT**

I since noticed that the shtender scenario is a previously discussed question on this forum [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34909/modifying-a-shtender-on-shabbos) - I wonder if this halacha is transferable to the scenario of a crutch?