# Tashmishei kedusha question: Putting a shtender on the bima

Tags: kedusha-holiness

Since a Torah is read on a bima, it would seem that the bima acquires tashmishei kedusha (a level of holiness) due to it being a support for the Torah.  How then can we put a (small) shtender ([What in the world is a shtender?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1009/what-in-the-world-is-a-shtender)) on the bima? The shtender only holds a siddur and so seems to have no level of holiness, certainly not a level like the bima.  How can an object of no or low holiness be placed on an object of a higher level of holiness.  What is the logic or rationale?

Comment: Adding a source that items cannot be placed on items of greater sanctity -  the basic premise of this question, would improve it.

Comment: Do I need to have separate shtenders for chumash and navi?

Comment: It's a "curious" question for now. Can you prove / demonstrate that the "shulchan" is considered among *Tashmishei kedusha*? That's besides the other questions, esp. the one from @mevaqesh. To disprove your assumption, I think tefillin bags are considered *tashmishei kedusha* (I think they are explicitly listed in Talmud - I think it's in mas. Megillah.) Clearly, one may have a pile of tefillin bags, and, AFAIK, one may place a siddur on top of a tefillin bag.

Comment: "argument point" - If the shtender is used to support the siddur, wouldn't that make the shtender "tashmishei kedusha", similar to a Torah Yad? (It is just a finger pointer, after all, no?) If that's the case, one is allowed to pile tashmishei kedusha on top of each other, AFAIK.